# JQuery Fade On Hover Effect - help?

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover, clone

I'm trying to achieve a fade-on-hover effect with JQuery. Currently I have an element with a "hov" class attacked to it, without javascript the css will simply change it's color on :hover. With JQuery.

The idea is to clone the element as it's rolled over and place it directly infront, stripping it of the "hov" class so it's just static. Then I fade it out so it create the transition effect.

I'm having trouble though, after I strip the "hov" class from the clone, it KEEPS acting as though its still there. I can mouse over the clone even though it shouldn't be able to be targeted through hov. Any ideas / tips?

```
<a href="#" class="hov rounded-50 action-button">Fade Me Out< /a>

$(".hov").mouseover(function() {

    // Clone the current element, remove the "hov" class so it won't trigger same behavior
    // finally layer it infront of current element

    var $overlay = $(this).clone(true).removeClass("hov").insertAfter($(this));

    // Push it to the side just for testing purposes - fade it out

    $overlay.css({left:'300px'}).fadeOut({duration:500, ease:'easeOutQuad'});
});
```

Comment: I've added my example to JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m2chK/1/   - I want the clone to be static, (not be clickable) and the original element to go through with its normal CSS hover state.

Answer (score 1):

No need to clone the element, just fade the original element:

```
$('.hov').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});

// Optionally:
$('.hov').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
```

You can also use the hover function:

```
$('.hov').hover(function(){
  $(this).fadeOut();
},
function(){
  $(this).stop(true, true).show();
});
```

If you just want it to partially fade, you can animate the opacity property:

```
$('.hov').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).animate({'opacity': 0.5});
});
```

If you just want it to pulse, then return to normal opacity:

```
$('.hov').mouseenter(function() {
  $this = $(this);

  $this.animate({'opacity': 0.5}, {
    'complete': function(){
      $this.animate({'opacity': 1});
    }
  });
});
```

Finally, if your willing to forgo support of older browsers, you can do it all with css:

```
.hov {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in;   
}
.hov:hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that Zack, but if I were to fade the whole element itself the button would just disappear. I'm trying to overlay a copy of the button's initial state over the top, and fade it out. So ideally, when the element is hovered over - it changes states. And the JQuery creates the illusion of a transition: see this http://jsfiddle.net/m2chK/1/

Comment: @JCraine: Please see the later examples, you can do whatever state change you'd like using .animate on the original element.

Comment: The problem though, is I'm trying to create a very generic behaviour so the class can be applied to any element, regardless of how its made up. For instance, the button I'm targeting is made up of CSS3 gradients, so cannot utilise the CSS transition effects. By cloning it and then fading it on top, I can create a transition without specifying any further CSS. The clone fades away to reveal the CSS hover state and the without JQuery it's just the standard hover fallback.

Comment: @JCraine: Using CSS3 gradients would not prevent you from using CSS transitions.  In any case, using .animate is the most generic way of doing this (you can set any element's opacity).  Please realize that when you use the jQuery fade effects, all it is doing is animating the opacity CSS property. Cloning the object is not particularly efficient, and will make binding events to the button a bit of a pain.